# Attribute Status change scope to Global

Tags: attributes, multistore, product-attribute

I have a magento single store website with multiple store views.
Sometimes I see attributes values of products like status are not set on default so generate confusion between store views.
Are there possible problems if I change the scope of the attribute "status" from Website to Global?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you will have to remove existing website specific entries in the attribute value tables manually otherwise they'll just stay there and keep being used.

You can use a query like this (make a backup first!)

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id > 0 and attribute_id = 4711
```

Replace **4711** with the attribute id and **int** with the value type. You can look up both in the `eav_attributes` table.