# How to set attribute scope default global via sql

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

[image]

How can I change the Scope value from store view to global?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attribute Status change scope to Global](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/attribute-status-change-scope-to-global)

Comment: DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id > 0 and attribute_id = 4711 Checked this query but didn't get attribute_id is 4711.this problem is diffrent

Answer (score 3):

write an install or update script for one of your modules with this content

```
<?php 
$this->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here', 'is_global', Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL);
```

But make sure that in your `config.xml` under the `setup` tag  inside the `resources` tag you have this:

```
 <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
```